# Node Js with mySQL return Null

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to Skip the data if there is nothing return from the mySql Database
How can I achieve it?

Here is my code

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
function dbconnection() {
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'DB'
});
var Data_export = dbconnection();
      Data_export.query(sql, function (err, data, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (data !== Null) {
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            fastcsv
                .write(jsonData, { headers: true })
                .on("finish", function () {
                    console.log("Write to file.csv successfully!");
                })
                .pipe(ws);
        } else { console.log("Nothing"); }
```

But it doesn't work
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "it doesn't work" is an opinion, not a problem description. It's also the wrong opinion: this code is doing exactly what you told it to do. So: instead of saying it doesn't work, edit your post to explain what you _expected_ it to do, what you see it do instead, and what you've already looked at/debugged/console logged etc. to find out where and hopefully why it's not living up to your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You must return something on your connection's function, and the code has some syntax issues.

It must work:

```js
function dbconnection() {
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'DB'
    });

    return connection;
}

var Data_export = dbconnection();
Data_export.query(sql, function (err, data, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (data !== Null) {
        const jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        fastcsv
            .write(jsonData, { headers: true })
            .on("finish", function () {
                console.log("Write to file.csv successfully!");
            })
            .pipe(ws);
    } else { 
        console.log("Nothing"); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

Because it is a return array from the mysql,
So instead of

```
        if (data !== Null) {
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            fastcsv
                .write(jsonData, { headers: true })
                .on("finish", function () {
                    console.log("Write to file.csv successfully!");
                })
                .pipe(ws);}
```

I use this one

```
        if (data.length !==0) {
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

            //write duplication to CSV file 
            fastcsv
                .write(jsonData, { headers: true })
                .on("finish", function () {
                    console.log("Write to file.csv successfully!");
                })
                .pipe(was); }
```